# Ubuntu 18.04.02 won't boot to desktop just black screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, kubuntu, macbook-pro

Running Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS (Kubuntu) on a Macbook Pro (2013 or 2015 I think) and I am having an issue when I boot. It takes around 5 minutes to get to a black screen with only the mouse pointer visible. Ubuntu is the only OS I have installed and I don't recall changing or updating anything but everything was running fine one day and then the next day I booted I ran into this problem.

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and get to the command line and start the desktop fine with the command "startx" but it is annoying to have to go through this process.

Does anyone have a way I could begin to troubleshoot this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your gnome desktop doesn't load correctly.
Since you access a secondary terminal try to reinstall gnome desktop.
Try reinstalling the gnome-session package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session
```